# How to prevent new tabs from opening in a window in dragablz:TabablzControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I used dragablz (TabablzControl) to display windows in WPF.

When a user wants to open a window, a new tab opens for each click, in which case several tabs are opened from one window, which is not a good display.

How can I restrict only one tab from each window?

I used the code below to create and call windows in the tab

xaml Codes :

```
   <grid>
       <dragablz:TabablzControl x:Name="drag_TabControl" 
                  FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" S
                   howDefaultCloseButton="True">
           <dragablz:TabablzControl.RenderTransform>
                 <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
         </dragablz:TabablzControl.RenderTransform>
    </dragablz:TabablzControl>
 </grid>
```

C# Codes :

```
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    Win_Report win = new Win_Report();
    TabItem item = new TabItem
       {
          Content = win.Content,
          Header = "Reprot Sells",
          IsSelected = true
        };
    drag_TabControl.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Simple mode can be used TabContorl

Comment: I still could not find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I used a counter that counts the number of open tabs, and if there is more than one open tab, it shows the current tab, and when the tab closes, the counter becomes zero.